# Using multithreading for loading JSON data

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlrequest

I want to load JSON data through multithreading and parse it to NSDictionary, have done it previously using TWRequest class for twitter feeds, How can I use NSURLRequest to do the same as:

```
TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json?screen_name=firdous_ali86&include_entities=true"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    // Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
         {
             tweetCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             Tweet *tweet;
             NSError *error;  

             NSArray *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
         }
    }];
```

problem is that NSURLRequest doesnt implement performRequestWithHandler method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://my_service_url"] //2

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    myCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                        kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization 
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                                  options:kNilOptions 
                                  error:&error];

        NSArray* myArray = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"response"]; //2

        NSEnumerator *myIterator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
        id anObject;

        Cast *cast;

        while( anObject = [myIterator nextObject])
        {
            cast = [[Cast alloc] init];    
            cast.castTitle = [anObject objectForKey:@"castTitle"];

            [myCollection addObject:cast];
        }
        [myTableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Comment: I think that you should call the reloadData tableView method from the main thread. In the apple documentation, you can find this: Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your application’s user interface in any way.  For more details see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Answer (score 1):

you can always create a delegate and let that delegate to call back after completion, Or use connection did finish loading delegate method of `NSURLConnection` to process twitter response. Or the best idea is to use `ASIHTTPRequest` or `AFNetwork` framework to make request async and then do `JSON` parsing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSURLConnection` with the method:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my most popular answer of the week. Look at Apple's docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i

The answer is right in there.

Does anyone actually read the documentation before coming to stack overflow?

Comment: i dont see blocks being used there, and no alternative of using performRequestWithHandler method